# Can I use an Apple charger to charge my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and PS4 Controller's Mini USB?

Tags: usb, pi-2

I have an Apple charger that says:

> 12W - USB Power Adapter 2012
>
> Input: 100-240V ~ 0.5A (0,5A)
>
> 50-60Hz Output: 5.2V === 2.4A

I also have a PS4 with its controller - they used Mini-USB, so will it work? My dad doesn't know much about volts and all so he didn't know.

Comment: the apple power adapter (assuming it has the right USB connector) should be OK. I don't know about the PS4 controlers

Comment: See also [Power supply for Raspberry Pi 2 Model B](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34987/power-supply-for-raspberry-pi-2-model-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB stands for *Universal Serial Bus*. Generally speaking, anything that charges with a USB cable should be using 5V. The only thing I would worry about is the device not being able to output the required amperage.

As Steve commented, the Apple is fine. So long as the PS4 controller meets the minimum power output requirements, it too will be acceptable. Below is a list of the minimum power requirements, taken from the Raspberry Pi Foundation's [website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs).

```
Raspberry Pi Model A    700mA   500mA   200mA
Raspberry Pi Model B    1.2A    500mA   500mA
Raspberry Pi Model A+   700mA   500mA   180mA
Raspberry Pi Model B+   1.8A    600mA/1.2A (switchable) 330mA
Raspberry Pi 2 Model B  1.8A    600mA/1.2A (switchable)
```

Comment: I just checked the PS4 controller and it said: DC 5V == 800mA and my Raspberry model says 600mA/1.2A on that list. So I just met the requirements!